# Что лучше и безопаснее: private переменная экземпляра или локальная переменная в публичном методе?

Tags: java, android

Что лучше и безопаснее: private переменная экземпляра или локальная переменная в публичном методе, которая передает аргумент в другой метод?

Пример для полного понимания:

Требуется вывести результат сложения какого-то значения.

Есть два варианта:
1) Создаем переменную экземпляра `private int mNum;`
и используем её в методе `mNum = 127+5;` , и выводим эту переменную на экран пользователя в другом методе без передачи ему аргумента засчет переменной экземпляра.

2) создаем в методе локальную переменную `int mNum = 0;` , далее выполняем действие `mNum = 127+5;` и передаем эту переменную в метод для дальнейшего вывода на экран `doSomething(mNum);`

Какой вариант лучше и безопаснее?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528115/Где-правильно-инициализировать-обьекты/529279#529279

Comment: @iFr0z опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я могла его отметить, как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе официальной [статьи](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/5-ways-to-optimize-your-code-for-android-5.0-lollipop) от Intel, с уверенностью могу сказать, что второй вариант будет правильней. Лучше стараться избегать общедоступные поля, т.к:

> Ограничивая область видимости переменных, вы не только улучшите
>   читаемость кода и уменьшите число потенциальных ошибок, но и сделаете
>   его лучше подходящим для оптимизации.

К сожалению, статья более не доступна на русском, но в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529279/205563) я не поленился и опубликовал весь текст, когда ещё был доступ.

Также советую ознакомиться и с другими ответами.

Answer (score 7):

Здесь нужно смотреть на контекст задачи. Но из того, что вы написали могу написать так: 
Понадобится ли вам эта переменная еще когда либо? Если нет, то лучше параметром. Зачем ее хранить в памяти экземпляра класс?

Что будет если метод doSomething() выполнится до того как вы измените свою приватную переменную? надо подумать.

Будет ли эта переменная высчитываться в разных местах? Будет ли она высчитываться за пределами класса?

Если эту приватную переменную можно назвать свойством объекта класса по смыслу, то оставляйте приватным свойством.

По поводу безопасности, просто проверяйте значение этой переменной внутри метода. Или используйте тайпхинтинг.

Вот.

Comment: Спасибо вам, написано всё по делу.